# full calendar - add extra attribute to event object

Tags: php, jquery, json, fullcalendar

Probably due to my lack of understanding, but I am bringing back the event data using PHP returning a JSON string.

```
<?php

  $json = array();

  // Query that retrieves events
  $requete = "SELECT * FROM DoctorAvailability ORDER BY id";

   try {
        $bdd = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname",$username,$password);
      } catch(Exception $e) {
        exit('Unable to connect to database.');
      }
     // Execute the query
    $resultat = $bdd->query($requete) or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));

    echo json_encode($resultat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
 ?>
```

Within the database there are six fields.

```
Id, title, start, end, backgroundColor, name.
```

I was wanting to bring back the name although say for instance within eventClick i try

```
 eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
           calEvent.name;
```

it doesn't exist.

I know there is something missing from my understanding, but I've spent ages Googling to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

You might look at using `eventRender` which allows you to access non-standard fields that are added.

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    console.log(event.name);
}
```

From the [docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/):

> In addition to the fields above, you may also include your own
>   non-standard fields in each Event Object. FullCalendar will not modify
>   or delete these fields. For example, developers often include a
>   description field for use in callbacks such as eventRender.

**Update:**

This is what I use to construct the data for my events:

```
// construct the array
foreach ($events as $e) {
    $eventList[] = array(
        'id' => 'event-' . $e->id, // unique identifier for aligning editing window 
        'allDay' => false, // makes the times show
        'title' => $e->fullname, // shows the user's name
        'start' => $e->start_time, // their start time (start working)
        'end' => $e->end_time, // their end time (done working)
        'notes' => $e->notes ? $e->notes : '', // notes, if applicable
        'className' => 'event-' . $e->id,
        'user' => $e->user
    );
};

// echo the data, json encoded for the calendar
echo json_encode($eventList);
```

Then I access specific data as mentioned above, using `eventRender`.

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    element.qtip({
        content: event.notes, // This is a non-standard, custom attribute!
        position: {
            my: 'top left',
            at: 'bottom left'
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: Thanks, just had a look and .name isn't available

Comment: @barryspikebob it should be available, this is the correct way to access non-standard fields. Is there any data in the `event` object?

Comment: `eventRender: function(event, element){ event.name }` this shows `expression is not assignment or call`

Comment: Try changing `event.name` to `console.log(event)`. It might be due to the data not being properly loaded into the event in your SQL query.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include what I have used on a project.

Comment: Thanks, at the moment the json returned as `{"id":"1","title":"Moe","start":"2015-11-30 09:00:00","end":"2015-11-30 10:00:00","backgroundColor":"green","Name":null}` should this mean it works

Comment: `Name` with a capital `N`. Try adjusting to `console.log(event.Name)` because yes, the data is being pulled correctly from the database so it should be working properly.